# What are the parameter naming conventions for packages?

Tags: stere-image-proc, image-view, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you determine the correct parameter names to send to a node?

I've noticed some variability in naming conventions around package parameters. Specifically, I'm trying to use [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) and [image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view), and each seems to use a mix of parameter names *with* and *without* a leading underscore. The wikis fail to mention which parameters require a leading underscore, and running package with either produces no explicit error, so it's difficult to determine which to use. However, occasionally a node will complain with a warning like:

```
Try restarting stereo_view with parameter _approximate_sync:=True
```

indicating an underscore should be used. Although both wiki pages mention the "approximate_sync" parameter, neither mention it must be prefixed with an underscore. How do you determine the correct usage?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209032/what-are-the-parameter-naming-conventions-for-packages?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not using "use a mix of parameter names with and without a leading underscore." Some of the names are parameter names, others are remapped topic names, see this answer:

http://answers.ros.org/question/209035/difference-between-roslaunch-and-rosrun-with-image_view/

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1